# Unable and Disable CheckBox in Swift UI on Toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui, checkbox, toggle

I want if user check the checkbox one then other one should be unchecked , currently user can select both.

I have seen some example but here I need to have bool values into modal struct but Please note that I do not have bool value into Model . Can I have do it with hardcoded values ?

Here is my CheckboxToggleStyle view code ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct CheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled
    let style: Style // custom param

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            configuration.isOn.toggle() // toggle the state binding
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.\(style.sfSymbolName).fill" : style.sfSymbolName)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                configuration.label
            }
        })
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // remove any implicit styling from the button
        .disabled(!isEnabled)
    }

    enum Style {
        case square, circle

        var sfSymbolName: String {
            switch self {
            case .square:
                return "square"
            case .circle:
                return "circle"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view code ...

```
struct OrderView: View {
    private var fee: Double = 5.00
    @State private var isOn1 = false
    @State private var isOn2 = false

    var body: some View {
                      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Toggle("Standard : Free ", isOn: $isOn1)
                            .toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle(style: .circle))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                //
                            }

                        Toggle("Express : Charge \(fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))", isOn: $isOn2)
                            .toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle(style: .circle))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                //

                            }
                    }
                }
```

Here is the screenshot.. when I select on checkbox other one should be disable but is not..

[image]

Comment: If the user checks one of your checkboxes, do you want to **disable** the other one, or un-check it? Joakim's answer lets you un-check the other checkbox, so they behave like radio buttons, but in your question you say "I want if user check the checkbox one then other one should be **disable**". If an item is disabled it doesn't respond to taps any more, and it is usually drawn in gray.

Comment: What do you suggest  for shopping cart app ?. Joakims answer solve the problem. but we want to disable other one what is the approach to do it ?

Comment: For a shopping app where you want the user to choose between free standard shipping and express shipping, I think it makes sense to have both checkboxes enabled and only allow one of them to be checked, but that's my opinion. (Jocakim's answer seems to provide a good user experience, but it isn't what you asked for.)

Comment: Ok . let me update the questions..

Comment: @DuncanC are you sure you have understood my solution correctly? I only set the other property to false if the changed property has been set to true so they aren’t behaving like radio buttons

Comment: You can also use picker instead of toggle to achieve this as many which needed

Comment: You said "...but we want to disable other one..." What does that mean? Is Joakim's solution what you are looking for, or do you want something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onChange`

```
.onChange(of: isOn1) { _, flag in
     if flag { isOn2 = false }
}
.onChange(of: isOn2) { _, flag in
     if flag { isOn1 = false }
}
```

Use `.onChange(of: isOn1) { flag in` for earlier versions of SwiftUI

Comment: The logic you posted in your answer force only one of the isOn variables to be true at a time. That makes them act like radio buttons, as I expected. Check out this GIF I made of the soulution you posted: https://media.giphy.com/media/w1qSDIqS0lTihU55hW/giphy.gif

Comment: Yes and that is the expected behaviour. Note that with my solution and as shown in your gif both buttons can be unchecked, this is not how radio buttons work in my opinion where one is always selected. I also believe this is what OP is saying in the first sentence of the question.